# R ggplot2 multiple column stacked histogram, separate bar for each column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a histogram of percentages for multiple columns of data in one graph. Is there a way to do this without transforming the data into an even longer format? Basically, I want to combine multiple histograms on one plot with the same y axis. I can't get `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` to work because everything is in different columns. Here is some sample data:

```
data <- data.frame("participant"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   "metric1"=c(0,1,2,0,1),
                   "metric2"=c(1,2,0,1,2),
                   "metric3"=c(2,0,1,2,0),
                   "date"=rep("8/14/2021",5))
```

Ideally, I would have a stacked bar for metric 1, next to that a stacked bar for metric 2, fianlly a stacked bar for metric 3. I can generate one stacked bar at a time with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = data, 
       aes(x = date, group = factor(metric1), fill=factor(metric1))) +  
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

How do I combine this graph with the graphs for metric 2 and 3 so that they are all on the same graph with the same axes? Can it be done without making the data long? My real data is more complicated than the test data, and I'd like to avoid transforming it. Thank you for reading and any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and create the `bar` plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('metric'), values_to = 'metric') %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = date, group = factor(metric),fill = factor(metric))) +  
       geom_bar() +    
      facet_wrap(~ name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The graph generated is not what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to get the graphs stacked by level of metric and faceted by metric, not participant (I have >500 participants in my real data).

Comment: @AmarisWilliams changed the facet_wrap to metric

Comment: That doesn't work, but this does: ```data %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('metric'), values_to = 'metric') %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = date, group = factor(metric), 
       fill = factor(metric))) +
    geom_bar() + 
    facet_wrap(~ name)```

Comment: @AmarisWilliams i was not sure about your group or fill columns

Comment: @AmarisWilliams if it works, please consider to upvote/accept solution